# Finding 2 disjoint closed but not bounded in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to find two disjoint closed sets $A$ and $B$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that are both closed but not compact (so in other words closed but not bounded). I've had a couple ideas but found errors in them. Here is a couple sets I came up with:

$$A = \{(x,0)|x \in R\}/(0,0) \; \text{and} \; B=\{(0,y)|y\in R\}/(0,0)$$ I know that $A^c$ and $B^c$ are not open however because there is no open ball around $(0,0)$ in that is a subset of either $A^c$ or $B^c$. Another attempt was:

$$A = \{(x,y)|y \geq\frac{1}{n} \text{for some}\; n \in \mathbb{N}\} \; \text{and} \; B=\{(x,0)|x\in R\}$$ however I'm quite sure $A^c$ is not open considering the set $A$ is just $A = \{(x,y)|y > 0\}$ by the Archimedes Principle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A=\{(x,y):xy=1, x>0\}$ and $B=\{(0,y): y \in \mathbb R\}$ provide an example.

Note that the distance between $(\frac  1n, n)$ and $(0,n)$ is $\frac  1 n$ which can be made less than $\epsilon$.

Comment: This is perfect thank you

Answer (score 2):

I have some easier subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ for you :

$$A=[(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2  : x\geq 1]$$
 $$B=[(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2  : x\leq -1]$$

Can you check these are disjoint closed and non compact?

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I realize however I left out a very important part of my question so I can't use these sets but still very helpful in trying to find ones that could work.